# Fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'sfml-system-s-d.lib'

Tags: c++, sfml

I'am getting an error shown below, I'am using visual studio 2017 community and I'am trying to run a project I downloaded from github.

> 1>------ Build started: Project: CurveFever, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>
> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'sfml-system-s-d.lib'
>
> 1>Done building project "CurveFever.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

So far I have already uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 and re installing it again, I have already tried searching for questions similar to mine and what I found did not work. I have already checked whether `sfml-system-s-d.lib` is in the directory of my `SFML` folder and its in there.

Comment: Did you add sfml-system-s-d.lib to the libraries in the VS project settings?

Comment: Is that the "#Additional Include Directories"  if I'am correct I have already put it there.

Comment: First of all the directory where the lib file is in must be in `VC++ Directories`. Secondly, yours is a linker problem, therefore, got to `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` and put the library name there. Note: This is for VS 2015, I assume same logic follows for 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linker seem not to be able to find 'sfml-system-s-d.lib'
You have to add the path to the library to the linker options:

*Right-klick on your project->Properties->Linker->Additional Library Directories*

Write the path to the folder containing your library, e.g. c:\lib\

Comment: Thank you very much sir but now I'am getting the error

Comment: 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'jpeg.lib'

Comment: You have to add all used path to the 'Additional Library Directories', you can add several path by splitting them with a semicolon ';' e.g. c:\Lib\;c:\Lib2; and so on.